# LinuxLite Terminal Intro

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc

How do i get rid of

`Welcome to Linux Lite 5.2 user Friday 13 November 2020, 00:00:00 Memory Usage: 1698/7913MB (21.46%) Disk Usage: 22/456GB (5%) Support - https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/ (Right click, Open Link)`

from the terminal start up?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Support for LinuxLite is available here: https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/index.php - If you post your question there, they should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your home directory

```
cd ~
```

Open the .bashrc file

```
nano .bashrc
```

Remove everyting below the line "#Linux Lite Custom Terminal" 
Do CTRL + O then enter to save 
Then CTRL + X to exit
Restart your terminal and the terminal intro should be gone